# Wordpress Blog on Subpage Link?

Tags: wordpress

Yes i've googled this topic and no i couldn't find a satisfying answer.
Pretty simple question: I want to use a static side as startpage for wordpress, that is easy. Only question - how do i link now on my "recent posts" page?

Thanks and best regards

Wolfgang

Comment: what is a static side? I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: oh you meant static site I think. One thing you can do is totally strip down your index.php so it just has a link to do recent posts, then at the top, or bottom, or wherever, of the page, do an `include '/path/to/mypage.php';`

Comment: thanks for your reply! but i have to admit i don't understand your solution. what do you mean "strip down your index.php so it just has a link to do recent posts, then at the top, or bottom, or wherever, of the page, do an include '/path/to/mypage.php'" ? what would be mypage.php in this example? best regards!

Comment: Actually you might not need to do all that. I think that you can just get the URL for recent posts, and then add that to your static homepage